# Django send http response without changing page

Tags: python, django

In Django, if i want to retrieve a POST form, scan the data, if the data has an error like password does NOT match the confirmed password how do i do that?

IE; The user inputs 123 in password and 1234 in confirm password, without changing or refreshing the website or anything like that, how do i send back a response stating 'passwords do not match' similarly, in a login form, if the user credentials they inputed does not match, how do i send it back.

(New to Django, found my errors from dirkgroten answer thanks! Also reason i couldnt get answers on this is because i couldn't phrase it correctly to search!)

Comment: It looks like you're confusing things. The browser always displays the URL of the **request** it made to receive the response. The response itself has **nothing to do with the URL** unless it redirects to a different URL.

Comment: In general, you fetch an initial form (GET request) and submit a filled form (POST request) to the **same URL** (and same view in Django). So there's no need for a "submit" at the end of your url. If the form is not valid, your view returns the errors, but the **request** was made to the same URL the form was initially on, so it doesn't change.

Comment: @dirkgroten hmm i do see what you are suggesting, but is it possible for you to phrase it in an answer a bit more clearly? As i mentioned, i'm a bit new to django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL shown in a browser is the URL of the **HTTP request** that lead to the response it renders. So if you have a page at URL `/appname/` that submits a form at URL `/appname/submit/` then the response received (assuming it's a HTTP 200 OK) will be rendered by the browser with the URL `/appname/submit/` and there's **nothing you can do at the back-end** to influence that. So what you want is **not possible**. Of course you can always redirect (HTTP 302 Redirect) to a different URL, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

You don't give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, but the login form mentioned seems to indicate that you're submitting a form to a different URL than the original URL used to fetch the form. **Don't do that**. Use one URL (and one view) to render and process the form:

- With a GET request, you return the page with the empty (or initial) **unbound** form (HTTP 200).
- With a POST request and invalid data, you return the same page with the filled **bound** form and errors (HTTP 200).
- With a POST request and valid data, you process the data and **redirect** to a different page showing success (HTTP 302).

Look at [working with forms docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) to see an example. This is how you should do it for every form.

Note that on many websites nowadays, forms are submitted via ajax (XHR). That allows you to submit your form in the background without refreshing the page. The javascript can submit it to any URL (on the same domain) since that won't affect the URL the user sees, and the javascript takes care of updating the various elements in the page depending on the response. It also allows you to put the same form on multiple different pages (e.g. a login popup form in the top navigation bar of your website, which is shown on every page of your website).